# Getting an error when getting the path using macro

Tags: vba, path, libreoffice-calc

After searching online for a solution to getting the current path of the file into a LibreOffice Calc cell, I came across the following macro code:

```
function GetPath() as string
  GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.loadLibrary("Tools")
  GetPath = Tools.Strings.DirectoryNameoutofPath(ThisComponent.url, "/")
end function
```

This works until I close the file, then re-open it.  When I re-open it, I get the following error message:

```
Inadmissible value or data type.
Index out of defined range.
```

This error is generated on the last line of the following function within the Tools Macro library.

```
Function FileNameoutofPath(ByVal Path as String, Optional Separator as String) as String
Dim i as Integer
Dim SepList() as String
    If IsMissing(Separator) Then
        Path = ConvertFromUrl(Path)
        Separator = GetPathSeparator()      
    End If
    SepList() = ArrayoutofString(Path, Separator,i)
    FileNameoutofPath = SepList(i)
End Function
```

The code for that function is...

```
Function ArrayOutOfString(BigString, Separator as String, Optional MaxIndex as Integer)
    Dim LocList() as String
    LocList=Split(BigString,Separator)

    If not isMissing(MaxIndex) then maxIndex=ubound(LocList())  

    ArrayOutOfString=LocList
End Function
```

I'm not sure why this would generate an error on file load, but continue to work thereafter.

Any idea?  Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code for `ArrayoutofString` ?

Comment: I have added the code for that function to the original post

Comment: If you debug then is there content in `SepList()` ?  What's the value of `i` when it errors?

Comment: After investigating a little further, it seems like it only generates the error during file load.  Once the file has loaded, I can use the function as above with no issues.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the timing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a better way.

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename");FIND("#$";CELL("filename"))-1)
```

Source: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/67271/how-to-automatically-display-file-path-in-a-cell/
Documentation on CELL function: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Information_Functions#CELL

Alternatively, to do it with a macro, assign the following `WritePath` subroutine to run on the `View created` event.

```vb
function GetPath() as string
    On Error Goto ErrorHandler
    GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.loadLibrary("Tools")
    GetPath = Tools.Strings.DirectoryNameoutofPath(ThisComponent.url, "/")
    ErrorHandler:
end function

Sub WritePath
    oSheet = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
    oCell.setString(GetPath())
End Sub
```

For an explanation of the problem and how the macro solution works, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39254907/5100564.

**EDIT**:

The following expression gives the path without the filename.  For it to work, regular expressions must be enabled in formulas under *Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Calculate*.

```
=MID(CELL("filename");2;SEARCH("/[^/]*$";CELL("filename"))-1)
```

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Regular_Expressions_in_Writer

Comment: I had not come across that.  However, that gives me the entire path including the file name.  I just want the path up to the containing directory.

Comment: that works perfectly!  Thank you for such a thorough answer.  Not only did I solve this issue, I now understand why it wasn't working.