# openoffice calc sumproduct with a twist

Tags: openoffice-calc, openoffice-basic

my first attempt in VBA apart from using simple functions; asking for a kick start here:

assume this (part of a) sheet

```
factor      b-count c-count d-count
A2          b2      c2      d2      ...
A3          b3      c3      d3      ...
```

Assume that these are the first columns and rows A1 to D3, holding numeric values each.

If `factor` is `1`, I want A(N) (column 'A', row `N >= 2`) to hold the sumproduct of row 1 and row N. 
The twist comes when `factor` is not `1`. In that case I want a sumproduct of 
`count*round(value * factor)`.

Example:

```
1.5         2       1       0       4
=myfunc(2)  4       8       11      15
=myfunc(3)  11      20      28      36
=myfunc(4)  29      53      74      94
```

where myfunc(2) should result in
`round(4*1,5)*2+round(8*1,5)*1+round(15*1,5)*4` = `6*2+12*1+23*4` = `12+12+92` = `116`, myfunc(3) = `17*2+30+54*4` = `34+30+216` = `280`, myfunc(4) = `44*2+80+141*4` = `88+80+564` = `732` etc.

I could just insert a row below each one, multiplying every value with the factor; but I would love something fancier.

basically thought (pun not intended):

```
col='B'
sum=0
do while (col)(N)>0
    sum=sum+(col)(1)*round((col)(N)*A1;0)
    col=col+1
loop
A(n)=sum
```

where (col)(N) refers to the cell in column `col` and row `N`.

Not important enough to study the manual; but it would be great if someone can do this off the cuff.

Another point: I have read that custom functions must be stored in the "Standard Library";
but I could not find any mention on HOW to do that. Who will point me to the right manual page?

Comment: The entire row, or just parts of a row? Where is your example data stored, and which `count` is to be used? In addition, where is `value` coming from? Is it only the `sumproduct` of row1 and rowN, or is it the `sumproduct` from row1 to rowN?

Comment: This question is well formatted, but not very clear.  What does "A2" mean -- is that a string, or does it mean column A, row 2?  If the latter, then what might it contain?  An actual example would help, rather than only variables.

Comment: Please remove the `vba` tag, as that is normally only used for MS Office. 
 Probably you want to add `libreoffice-basic` tag instead.  The languages are not the same.

Comment: @JimK updated. Did it become clearer?

Comment: @AJD The data is in columns B and further right. And it´s just parts of a row; actually it´s columns Z instead of A, AA instead of B and so on. The list is pretty open to the right; but you can assume that it ends when there is an empty cell in row `1` (or actually, currently row 76 in one sheet and 65 in another)

Comment: OK, the question is reasonably clear now.  It took me a long time to figure out that `1,5` is a decimal number because in my locale the decimal separator is `.`.  Part of my confusion was that`x69` should be `A1` in this example.

Comment: @JimK Whoops sorry. Fixed to `1.5` and `A1`.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> OpenOffice Basic*.  Select *My Macros -> `Standard` -> Module 1* (that is what is meant by the `Standard` library), and press *Edit*.

Paste the following code.

```vb
Function SumProductOfTwoRows(firstColumn As Long, row As Long, firstRow As Long)
    'For example: =SUMPRODUCTOFTWOROWS(COLUMN(); ROW(); ROW($A$1))
    firstColumn = firstColumn - 1  'column A is index 0
    row = row - 1  'row 1 is index 0
    firstRow = firstRow - 1  'row 1 is index 0
    oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    sum = 0
    column = firstColumn + 1
    factor = oSheet.getCellByPosition(firstColumn, firstRow).getValue()
    Do
        value = oSheet.getCellByPosition(column, row).getValue()
        count = oSheet.getCellByPosition(column, firstRow).getValue()
        If value = 0 Then Exit Do
        sum = sum + count * CLng(value * factor)
        column = column + 1
    Loop
    SumProductOfTwoRows = sum
End Function
```

Enter this formula in A2 and drag to fill down to A4.

```
=SUMPRODUCTOFTWOROWS(COLUMN(); ROW(); ROW($A$1))
```

The result:

[image: 116, 280, 732]

This kind of user-defined function produces an error when re-opening the file.  To avoid the error, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39254907/5100564.